# Create Dependent Attributes based on some selection in alfresco for document property page

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have one property page in alfresco. In property page i have one drop-down list and below drop-down list some other text-fields are there.

Now my requirement is that, based on selection i want to change below text-fields. Means i want to show or hide text-fields or text-area dynamically based on my selection.

and also i have two radio buttons, that is yes and no. if i will select yes then i want to show text field and if i will select no from radio button, i want to hide text field.

can anyone will help me with this, how can i achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I assume you're talking about Share?

Comment: Yes Lista, You are right.    I am creating document in alfresco share, and applying one property page.  But i want some dynamic nature on that property page as i mentioned above.  Do you have any idea???

Comment: Can any-one will suggest me that, either is it possible in alfresco-share or not.  Actually i did it through html and java script. But i want in side share. so need to do Using ftl only. please reply

Comment: Awaiting for response....................................................................!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the standard controls (ftl)s Alfresco Share provides.

But you could off course write your own custom controls and make them communicate to oneanother to achieve this feature. It would be a cool feature, I agree, but I haven t done your use case

The basics would be to load a piece of javascript in the ftl of your field, that will listen to events on a different field. In javascript you can get a different field like this:

```
_getSourceField: function() {
        var thisFieldName = this.id,
            baseFieldName = thisFieldName.substring(0, thisFieldName.substring(0, thisFieldName.lastIndexOf("_")).lastIndexOf("_")),
            sourceFieldName = baseFieldName + "_" + this.options.sourceField.replace(":", "_"),
            sourceField = Dom.get(sourceFieldName);
        return sourceField;
    },
```

Where this.options.sourceField is for example "cm:name"

```
 var elSource = this._getSourceField(),
  Event.addListener(elSource, "keyup", function() {
    //do something with my own field
  }
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, Please provide some sample custom control example. So it will be easy for me.  Actually i am a bit new in alfresco. so not having good command on these things.  Please help if possible.   Thanks in advance.